# realizar operaciones sean cuales sean el número de argumentos pasados a la función

Tags: javascript, funciones

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
function operaciones(...args){
    let sum = 0;
    for(let arg of args)
    sum += arg;    
    return sum; 
}

console.log(operaciones(4,5,5));
```

El resultado, en este caso, es 14; sin embargo, al restar me da -14, y al multiplicar o dividir es 0.  Cómo lo hago, sin importar la cantidad de argumentos pasados a la función, me de el resultado correcto según la operación a aplicar?

Comment: ¿Puedes aclarar que es lo que quieres que haga la función?, ¿que resultado debería darte en cada caso?

Comment: Hola @Parra!! El ejercicio es el siguiente: Necesito hacer una calculadora que, no importa la cantidad de argumentos pasados a la función, me realice las 4 operaciones aritméticas básicas(suma, resta, multiplicación, división)... Con la suma no hay problema, pero lo intento con el resto de operaciones ( resta, multipl. división) y no ejecuta el resultado deseado.

Comment: Tienes un problema de planteamiento, primero, ten en cuenta que al restar cualquier número a 0 el resultado será negativo, es decir, 0 - 1 = -1.

Lo mismo te pasa al multiplicar, 1*0 = 0. Al hacerlo en bucle, el resultado es 0.
Al dividir n/0 = Infinity.

Answer (score 4):

Tienes un pequeño problema de concepto, ten en cuenta que estás empezando a sumar/restar/multiplicar/dividir sobre una base '0', por eso sólo te sale bien en la suma.

Restar a cero cualquier número es igual a ese número en negativo, así que tu condición de partida es equivocada.

Multiplicar cualquier número por cero es igual a cero, por eso siempre te da igual a cero.

Te dejo un ejemplo hecho utilizando el método `.reduce()` de Array. A ver si te puede servir.

```js
const operaciones = (...args) => {
  const suma = args.reduce((a, b) => a+b);
  const resta = args.reduce((a, b) => a-b);
  const mult = args.reduce((a, b) => a*b);
  const div = args.reduce((a, b) => a/b);
  
  return {
    suma,
    resta,
    mult,
    div
  }
}

console.log(operaciones(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sí tengo hay una cosa que no entiendo : lo he estado probando y me funciona, pero al quitar las llaves , me ejecuta la última operación que en este caso es la división, por qué ocurre esto?

Comment: Tengo la ligera impresión de que esto era un comentario a mí respuesta. Te sugiero que lo pongas allí. Pero te respondo. Las llaves y los nombres de las variables es una notación particular para devolver objetos, al quitar las llaves estás devolviendo un valor absoluto, interpreta e último que recibe y por eso es lo que te da.

Comment: Muchas gracias @FernandoCarrascosa!! Siento no haberte respondido antes.